# App closes when item deleted from long list selector

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I've just made a simple app with a longlistseletor, which include an item and an button to delete this item. I think nothing is wrong but each time i delete 4 or 5 items from this list, app always close. Is it because of lack of RAM ?

btw, my english is bad, sorry :P

XAML code:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsIdea}">
    <!-- item quick idea template-->
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdeaContent}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2" Click="btDeleteIdea_Click" BorderThickness="0.0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Icons/cancel_small.png"/>                                                
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

and the C# code:

```
private void btDeleteIdea_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var button = (sender as Button).DataContext as IdeaViewModel;
    if (button != null)
        App.ViewModel.DeleteIdea(button);
}
```

Comment: i think your app is getting an exception when you are deleting item... you should debug your code to know the exception..

Comment: I think problem in your "DeleteIdea" method. debug DeleteIdea method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be connected with some little bugs in LongListSelector (I'm not aware if they still exist in current version and the version you use).

[Here you can find](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bec4efbf-269b-4be0-aacc-99c8be59b861/wp8-longlistselector-exception-when-removing-items?forum=wpdevelop) similar problem and the solution is to extend your LLS class. I had similar problem some time ago and this helped:

```
 public class LongListSelectorExtension : LongListSelector
{
    protected override System.Windows.Size MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize)
    {
        try { return base.MeasureOverride(availableSize); }
        catch (ArgumentException) { return this.DesiredSize; }
    }
}
```

You can also [look here](https://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/7629) where are some improvements to LLS code.

Maybe this will help.

---

To use your extension you will have to modify your XAML:

Add namespace of your project where the class is at the beginning where other xmlns are:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
```

Then you should be able to use your class in XAML file instead normal LLS:

```
 <local:LongListSelectorExtension .../>
```

Comment: just write class LongListSelectorExtension and what's next, how to use it ? plz help, i'm new to coding :(

Comment: @user3448806 I've edited my answer. And please don't mark answer as a solution if it didn't helped/solved the problem.

Comment: ok thank, finally it worked. no more crash ^^ just 1 little bug left: i added 6 items, and if i delete the third, it not crash anymore but the list doesnt update ( the 4th to 6th are still at there position, not push up), but while i have a pivot and when i swipe it and back, everything's fine. thanks

Comment: @user3448806 I haven't dug into source code of LLS much. I cannot say what to do in this case. But as you see the problem may not be with your code. If you are not using grouping, then use ListBox instead - there aren't such problems. And once you have found an answer usefull, you can mark it ;)